# Scala: Is hashCode() & equals() for case classes only generated if not already specified in a non-trivial superclass?

Tags: scala, inheritance

I tried to define an abstract class "Vertex" in such a way that all instances of all its subclasses are identified (in sets/maps/distinct, etc.) by the abstract field "id", even if the subclasses are different case classes that define additional individual parameters. Thus, I want to achieve that all subclasses call `hashCode() & equals()` as defined in the abstract superclass. In other words, for case classes that inherit from "Vertex" I want to disable the automatic overrides that are generated by the Scala compiler for case classes.

According to the following example, it seems to hold true that the Scala compiler does not generate `hashCode() & equals()` for a case class if that case class already has these functions explicitly defined in a non-trivial superclass:

```
abstract class AbstractVertex {
  val id: String

  // identify only by id, ignoring any additional fields of case classes

  override def hashCode(): Int = id.hashCode
  override def equals(obj: scala.Any): Boolean = {
    obj match {
      case other: AbstractVertex => other.id == id
      case _ => false
    }
  }
}

case class VertexType1(id: String, data: String) extends AbstractVertex

case class VertexType2(id: String, data: String) extends AbstractVertex

case class VertexType3(id: String, data: String) { // NOT an AbstractVertex
  // manually provide our own hashCode and equals
  override def hashCode(): Int = id.hashCode
  override def equals(obj: scala.Any): Boolean = {
    obj match {
      case other: VertexType3 => other.id == id
      case _ => false
    }
  }
}

case class VertexType4(id: String, data: String) // NOT an AbstractVertex

object Playground extends App {
  // create several vertices, all of the same id
  val v1a = VertexType1("x", "some")
  val v1b = VertexType1("x", "other")
  val v2a = VertexType2("x", "some")
  val v2b = VertexType2("x", "other")
  val v3a = VertexType3("x", "some")
  val v3b = VertexType3("x", "other")
  val v4a = VertexType4("x", "some")
  val v4b = VertexType4("x", "other")
  val v4c = VertexType4("x", "some")

  println(Set(v1a, v1b, v2a, v2b).size) // gives 1
  println(Set(v1a, v1b).size) // gives 1
  println(Set(v2a, v2b).size) // gives 1
  println(Set(v3a, v3b).size) // gives 1
  println(Set(v4a, v4b, v4c).size) // gives 2

  println(v1a == v1b) // gives true
  println(v1a == v2a) // gives true
  println(v1a == v3a) // gives false
  println(v1a == v4a) // gives false
  println(v4a == v4b) // gives false
  println(v4a == v4c) // gives true
}
```

Thus, the behavior is as intended. Even more, compiling the above code snippet via `scalac -Xprint:typer Playground.scala | grep "hashCode" -C 5` shows that `hashCode()` is only generated for `VertexType4`, and taken as explicitly defined for `VertexType3`, while `VertexType1` and `VertexType2` do not generate these, so they fall back to the `hashCode()` as defined in `AbstractVertex`. Similar for `equals()`.

So everything works fine as intended. However, since this is a quite subtle detail of how Scala's compiler deals with generating `hashCode() & equals()` for case classes, I wonder how "stable" this behavior is. There are often many changes between different Scala versions, so this might break in future. Can I rely on this behavior? For example, is there probably some official ticket or so, where this kind of behavior is explicitly specified?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is documented behavior. [Section §5.3.2 of the Scala specification](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html#case-classes) states (emphasis mine):

> Every case class implicitly overrides some method definitions of class scala.AnyRef **unless a definition of the same method is already given in the case class itself or a concrete definition of the same method is given in some base class of the case class different from AnyRef**. In particular:
>
> - Method equals: (Any)Boolean is structural equality, where two instances are equal if they both belong to the case class in question and they have equal (with respect to equals) constructor arguments (restricted to the class's elements, i.e., the first parameter section).
> - Method hashCode: Int computes a hash-code. If the hashCode methods of the data structure members map equal (with respect to equals) values to equal hash-codes, then the case class hashCode method does too.
> - Method toString: String returns a string representation which contains the name of the class and its elements.